# How to get columns in Import/Export Member CSVs to match in Silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a Silverstripe project with additional fields added to the Member object via a DataExtension:

```
class ClubMemberFields extends DataExtension {

  private static $db = array(
      'MembershipExpiresOn' => 'Date'
  );
```

If I go into Security > Users in the CMS I get the following message under "Import Users" > "Advanced Usage":

***Allowed columns:*** FirstName, Surname, Email, Password, RememberLoginToken, NumVisit, LastVisited, AutoLoginHash, AutoLoginExpired, PasswordEncryption, Salt, PasswordExpiry, LockedOutUntil, Locale, FailedLoginCount, DateFormat, TimeFormat, MembershipExpiresOn, ValidationKey, NeedsValidation, NeedsApproval, PublicFieldsRaw

Which is good because I want to import users with the "MembershipExpiresOn" field.

However when I select **Export to CSV** it only returns the following columns: *FirstName, Surname, Email*

How do I make it so it also exports the "MembershipExpiresOn" field to CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any additional summary fields are exported to the CSV:

```
class ClubMemberFields extends DataExtension {

  private static $db = array(
      'MembershipExpiresOn' => 'Date'
  );

  public static $summary_fields = array(
      'MembershipExpiresOn'

  );
```